# Python : Can pop() method work for 3 consecutive times?

Tags: python

I'm working on Python list operations. I'm trying to get a number of inputs from users and appending that to a list.

After that I validate the list elements if they are float values, if not I'll print the message as Invalid Input. Also, I want to eliminate if the value of user input is 42.195 from the list.

If I give the above value 3 times, my code is skipping the third existence of 42.195. How can I resolve this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
def isfloat(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

user_input = input("Enter the distance covered by racers in Marathon (Kilometers) please \n (press q to terminate):")
R = []


while user_input != 'q':
    R.append(user_input)
    user_input = input("Enter the distance covered by racers in Marathon (Kilometers) please \n (press q to terminate):")

print("R",R)
valid = False

def validate(R):
    for i in R:
        if isfloat(i) == False:
            print('Invalid Input')
            return False
        elif (float(i) < 0):
            print("Invalid Input")
            return False
        elif (float(i) > 42.195):
            print("Invalid Input")
            return False
        elif (float(i) == 42.195):
            x = R.index(i)
            print('x',x)
            R.pop(x)
    return True


if validate(R):
    print('R2:',R)
    R.sort(reverse= True)
    print(R[0:3])
    
    
    if validate(R):
      print('R2:',R)
      R.sort(reverse= True)
      print(R[0:3])
```

**Sample Input**

```
42.195
42.195
42.195
33.25
40
41.2
38.9
37.5
q
```

Comment: You should never delete items from a list over which you are iterating. Also, comparing a floating point number to the exact value 42.195 is problematic because of the intrinsic imprecision of floating point.

Comment: You need to change your title, you are not actually using `pop()`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry, I was trying with both pop() and del. I pasted the code when I was trying with del. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

From your function, you can remove the `elif` section that removes the occurrence of *42.195* and re-assign the original list without the value *42.195* by using **list comprehension.**

```
R = [i for i in R if float(i) != 42.195]
```

This should give you a list without an occurrence of the number *42.195*